# How to pickle an object which is written in c++ through pybind11?

Tags: python, c++, multiprocessing, pickle, pybind11

I use a package which is written in c++ through pybind11, and I get an object from this package. In order to improve the program's speed and make better use of my machine, I change the program into multi process by `multiprocessing.Process`, but I must share the c++ object to other process, and use a global variable to share it. Then it threw an exception `TypeError: can't pickle cityflow.Archive objects`, it seems that python use pickle to share data in multi process, so how can I pickle this object.

I create a `Manager().Queue()` in the main function `node_queue = Manager().Queue()`, and get an object in the main function `current_archive = node_queue.get()`, current_archive is an object contains the c++ object.

Then I use this object in the multi process function:`eng.load(current_archive.archive)` current_archive.archive is the c++ object,`node_queue.put(Node(tmp, num.value, tmp_flow))`tmp is a new c++ object which is created in the multi process function.

Answer (score 3):

Pybind11 has pickling support: https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/classes.html#pickling-support.
It works like this:

```cpp
py::class_<Archive>(m, "Archive")
    .def(py::pickle(
        [](const Archive& a) { // dump
            return py::make_tuple(a.member1, a.member2, a.member3);
        },
        [](py::tuple t) { // load
            return Archive{t[0].cast<T>(), t[1].cast<T>(), t[2].cast<T>()};
        }
    ));
```

and Python should handle it from there.

**For Python 2 specifically**, you have to use `cPickle` (not `pickle`), and manually specify pickle protocol version 2 (default is 1).

Comment: Hi, what if class `Archive` is, say, `vector<int>`? how can I pickle a `vector<int>`?

Comment: You'll need to convert it to a python object somehow. In this case you could use a list, but if you have general C++ objects you can use some C++ serialization library and use `py::bytes` as the python object you're pickling.

Comment: Thank you, I have few experiences in CPP and no experience in Pybind11. May I ask a new question in SO and could you help me to answer it?

Comment: Go for it, maybe other people can answer too :)